# Background Texture of a grouped UITableView won't scroll with the table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on an app that has lots of UITableViews and I'm trying to give them a textured background color.  I need to use the Grouped style because I don't want the section headers to  float over the text fields when the user scrolls.

**The problem I'm having is that when I use the Grouped style, the background texture doesn't scroll with the table;** it stays in place while the table scrolls above it.  I feel like this is kind of weird and I would rather have the background scroll with the table, the way it does in the Plain style.  Unfortunately, because I can't have the header views floating on top of everything, that doesn't appear to be an option.

Has anyone been able to accomplish this?

Here's some relevant code:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texturedPattern.png"]];
    // this prevents the cells from replicating the background texture
    self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // disable the default grouped border since we're doing it manually with the textField
    cell.backgroundView = nil;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

And my table view currently looks like this:
[image: Just to give you an idea...]

**UPDATE**

As Amit Vyawahare suggested, I tried applying the background texture to the background of the headers and each cell.  There are two problems that are both much more obvious when you see it in motion, but I'll do my best.

- First, the background is always visible.  *I've removed the background color from the table to make it more obvious*:

[image: Scrolling areas vs. non-scrolling areas]

Everywhere you see black, the background texture of the tableView would be visible and it *will not scroll with the tableView*.  The Grouped tableView style inserts the 5 pixel border on either side of every cell and can't be changed.  Additionally, there is no footer beneath the Staff ID section, and I've even implemented `-tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` to return 0.0, but there's still a gap there.

- Second, even if I were able to get rid of these gaps, the textures don't line up anyway.  Again, this is difficult to see, so I've uploaded a retina screen shot to make it a little easier:

[image: if you squint, you'll see a totally rad 3d image!]

This is most obvious above the Password section, you can see the textures don't align properly and it looks kind of like a "fold" in the paper.  Which would be cool, I guess, if that's what the client wanted.  It's visible, but less obvious on just about every edge from the second screen shot.  This is because the texture is actually quite large: 200x200 (400x400@2x), and there are slight variations in color that aren't noticeable *unless* this sort of misalignment happens.

Comment: Why cant you create a Costume cell with the texture background ?

Comment: The textured background is actually quite large, 200x200.  Even if I were able to apply it to the background of every cell and every header and footer in the entire app, which I'm sure would be a TON of work, you'd be able to tell where each cell began because the repeating textures wouldn't line up properly.

Comment: 200x200 is not large. I am doing similar thing is my project. Create a Costume cell dump all the information you want in that and use that cell in TableVIew. If you still can't do it dump your code and let me see how difficult is to do my solution.

Comment: If you can dump your code some where, I will solve the problem.

Comment: I can't share my code because it's work I'm doing for a client.  If you could explain how you would fix it in an answer, I'd be more than happy to give you a big check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace your UITableViewController by a UIViewController and add a UITableView to it. Set the autoresizingMask to flexible width/height. Now you have something equivalent to a UITableViewController, but with more control over the view hierarchy.

Then add a view below the tableview (actually: add that one first) which holds the background.

Finally, set the delegate of the scrollview to your class, and respond to scroll events by updating your background view accordingly.

Comment: I took your idea and ran with it.

Comment: 1. Convert the view from a subclass of UITableViewController to a subclass of UIViewController. 2. Add a UIScrollView with the texture behind the tableview. 3. Observe and sync changes to the tableView's `contentSize` and `contentOffset` to the scrollView. 4. Observe the keyboard appearance and modify the frame of the tableView.  Now, I'm going to consolidate that code into a class so I don't have to repeat it on every view in the app.